# How to run an event on Enter key in Excel VBA?

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba

I'd like to have Excel change to a predefined data in any cell in column A whenever the user hits the Enter key (instead of the default go to next cell behavior). How can I achieve this in VBA?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try do it in Workbook_open event

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    Application.OnKey "{ENTER}", "MyEnterEvent"
End Sub

Sub MyEnterEvent

    ' codes here

End Sub
```

To end Macro

```
Application.OnKey "{ENTER}"
```

Comment: Thank you! It didn't work at first, but I played around and got this:  `Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)  
    Application.OnKey "~", "MyEnterEvent"  
End Sub`

Comment: It should be unnecessary to keep re-assigning this key-event every time the selection changes. Obviously, I'm not aware of what your code actually does, but perhaps this key assignment could be made, and removed, on the sheet's `Activate` and `Deactivate` events.

Comment: @AndyG .. thanx for your correction ..