# How do I add current time in Excel with just a single keystroke

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, time

I am trying to add the current time to a cell with just a single key. I was hoping to use x to input the current time but can't seem to work it out.

I have a huge checklist in Excel and need the time each check was performed. It is time consuming entering the time manually so i just want to hit one letter to do it.

Comment: Try to record a macro with =NOW() formula, then add the macro to Quick access tool.

Answer (score 1):

Just use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>;</kbd>

> ## Insert a static date or time into an Excel cell
>
> A static value in a worksheet is one that doesn’t change when the worksheet is recalculated or opened. When you press a key combination such as <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>;</kbd> to insert the current date in a cell, Excel “takes a snapshot” of the current date and then inserts the date in the cell. Because that cell’s value doesn’t change, it’s considered static.
>
> - On a worksheet, select the cell into which you want to insert the current date or time.
> - Do one of the following:
>
>   - To insert the current date, press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>;</kbd> (semi-colon).
>   - To insert the current time, press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>;</kbd> (semi-colon).
>   - To insert the current date and time, press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>;</kbd> (semi-colon), then press <kbd>Space</kbd>, and then press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>;</kbd> (semi-colon).
>
> ## Insert a date or time whose value is updated
>
> A date or time that updates when the worksheet is recalculated or the workbook is opened is considered “dynamic” instead of static. In a worksheet, the most common way to return a dynamic date or time in a cell is by using a worksheet function.
>
> To insert the current date or time so that it is updatable, use the `TODAY` and `NOW` functions, as shown in the following example. For more information about how to use these functions, see `TODAY` function and `NOW` function.
>
> [Insert the current date and time in a cell](https://support.office.com/en-ie/article/insert-the-current-date-and-time-in-a-cell-b5663451-10b0-40ab-9e71-6b0ce5768138)

Answer (score 0):

Touch:

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>;</kbd>

This is a built-in key combo.

Answer (score 0):

If you can use a macro, you would be interested in the following solution here in Super User: [How to run an event on Enter key in Excel VBA?](https://superuser.com/questions/614142/how-to-run-an-event-on-enter-key-in-excel-vba)

In there's a simple demonstration of `Application.OnKey`.

You would do two things to the basic framework provided:

1. Build an `IF` around the action. IF the cell is in the column or range your timestamp entries would be placed, then pressing the desired key (<kbd>x</kbd> is fine, others could be chosen as well) would fire the event code.
2. Write the actual event code (`MyEnterEvent` in his framework). This would place the current time in the cell and anything else useful. For example, if minimal work is a goal, it could move the cell selection down one row the next place one might desire to examine and timestamp and save a keystroke moving on as well. (This would not be insurmountable, just a couple lines.)

The IF's largest purpose would be to keep it from happening in other places than the desired column or range.

If you cannot use a macro, Gary's Student has your best answer. Mmm... technically, it could be made shorter using a couple tricks to implement it, but those would only make it a matter of pressing 2 keys together vs. the 3 designed into MS's shortcut, not a single key press as desired. And again, the macro could gain you a keystroke you did not even wish for.